# Weird commands in the book Eloquent JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My question is with regards to the popular book "Eloquent JavaScript."

It seems to be a very popular book and appears to be on most "recommended reading" lists for people that wish to learn JS. After starting to read the book, I can certainly understand why: the author is an excellent writer and has a knack for explaining things in a very clear and concise way. What confuses me are the commands he often calls, in the first little bit he uses

```
Print("hehehe")
```

and

```
Show(sum(range(1,10)))
```

to add all numbers from 1 to 10. But none of those commands appear to be consistent with other tutorials and dont work when I try to run them.

What the heck is going on?! Has the language changed THAT much since the book was published in 2007?

Thanks guys and I apologize if this questions is a dumb one.

Comment: There can be any number of reasons why a line of code won't run.  What is the exact wording of the error message that you receive?

Comment: if i run this in the chrome-console you get "Print is not defined" so its a refference error, i want to see the context, @pyth could you please link to the site ? heres the ebook http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [web version](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) of the book? He explains in chapter 2:

> As the previous examples show, `alert` can be useful for showing the result of some expression. Clicking away all those little windows can get on one's nerves though, so from now on we will prefer to use a similar function, called `print`, which does not pop up a window, but just writes a value to the output area of the console. *`print` is not a standard JavaScript function*, browsers do not provide it for you, but it is made available by this book, so you can use it on these pages.
>
> A similar function, also *provided on these pages*, is `show`. While `print` will display its argument as flat text, `show` tries to display it the way it would look in a program, which can give more information about the type of the value. For example, string values keep their quotes when given to `show`:

Comment: In other words the `Show` and `range` functions are in the book, not native to Javascript.  You have to include the code for those functions in your script, otherwise Javascript won't recognize those functions.